# Not able to call start_query method

Tags: amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

Not able to call start_query method

I am trying to query cloudwatch Logs with the below code. But I got the below error 
    `TypeError: cloudwatchlogs.startQuery` is not a function

It seems the API was not able to find startQuery method. 
Kindly help me resolve the issue.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var cloudwatchlogs = new AWS.CloudWatchLogs({apiVersion: '2014-03-28',
  region: 'us-west-2'
});
// Set the region 
exports.handler = (event,context,callback) => {
    console.log("hai");
    AWS.config.update({region: 'us-west-2'});
    var params = {
      endTime: 1553686248, /* required */
      logGroupName: '/aws/lambda/tset', /* required */
      queryString: 'fields  @message| filter @message like /START/| fields strcontains(@message, "$LATEST") as @CONTAINS_ap | stats sum(@CONTAINS_ap) as @sample',
      startTime: 1553538648,
      limit: 0
    };
      cloudwatchlogs.startQuery(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      else     console.log(data);           // successful response
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What version of the 'aws-sdk' are you using? StartQuery was added in `2.364.0`: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#23640

Comment: can you provide one good example to execute the startQuery.  i am getting below error while executing my query"  message:
   'token recognition error at: \' \' (Service: AWSLogs; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedQueryException; Request ID: f949299b-b5ea-431e-aeb9-45834fcae19a)',
  code: 'MalformedQueryException',

Comment: Query from above looks good, I was able to execute it without problems (just had to change limit to be larger than 0).

Comment: Thanks for your response, now i am able to get the result, now the result is getting as a String value, if i execute the above query in the Clouwatch- insights  i am getting a number, how can i convert this response query id in to a value ?

Comment: how to find out and bundle-id for a start query ? i am trying to use a describeBundleTasks with ref of below url (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#describeBundleTasks-property) how to identify the bundle id and i am getting an error StateNotFoundError: State bundleTaskComplete not found. how to resolve it

Comment: Incidentally: I know the OP was asking about Node/JS, but if you are interacting with CloudWatch Logs via the API and you code in Go, I strongly suggest the Incite library - https://github.com/gogama/incite.

It streamlines the API, replaces unpleasant concepts like polling with convenient ones like streaming, and supports multiplexing, chunking, unmarshaling the results into arbitrary data structures just like `encoding/json`. Docs [here](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gogama/incite).